# Creating Word file from ObservableCollection with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, observablecollection

I have an observable collection with a class that has 2 string properties: Word and Translation. I want to create a word file in format:

---

**word** = translation             **word** = translation

**word** = translation             **word** = translation...

---

The word document needs to be in 2 Columns (PageLayout) and the Word should be in bold.

I have first tried Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. 
`PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2)` sets the PageLayout. As for the text itself I used a foreach loop and in each iteration I did this:

```
paragraph.Range.Text = Word + " = " + Translation;
object boldStart = paragraph.Range.Start;
object boldEnd = paragraph.Range.Start + Word.Length;
Word.Range boldPart = document.Range(boldStart, boldEnd);
boldPart.Bold = 1;

paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

This does exactly what I want, but if there are 1000 items in the collection it takes about 10sec, much much more if the number is 10k+. I then used a StringBuilder and just set `document.Content.Text = sb.ToString();` and that takes less than a sec, but I can't set the word to be bold that way.

Then I switched to using Open XML SDK 2.5, but even after reading the msdn documentation I still have no idea how to make just a part of the text bold, and I don't know if it's even possible to set PageLayout Columns count. The only thing I could do was to make it look the same as with Interop.Word, but with just 1 column and <1sec creation time.

Should I be using Interop.Word or Open XML (or maybe combined) for this? And can someone pls show me how to write this properly, so it doesn't take forever if the collection is relatively large? Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Avoid interop whenever possible (and it's possible in your case)

Comment: You can download Open XML SDK Productivity tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). You can use it to see the xml code generated when you make a word-document and it also shows the c# code you'd need to generate it

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I had Productivity tool downloaded, but didn't install it yet. After seeing your comment I installed it, made a test word document, spent maybe 1-2min in the tool, found out what I needed to know and wrote the code in VS... I had previously spent more than 5hours reading/learning about Interop and Open XML SDK and trying to code it just right. I had the wrong idea of what this tool was when I downloaded it. Thanks for the simple, but great advice :D

Comment: @VincentProxy yeh, the documentation for open xml sdk is horrible, but at least that tool is awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOXML can be intimidating at first. http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML.php has some good examples. Whenever you get confused unzip the docx and browse the contents to see how it's done.

The basic idea is you'd open Word, create a template with the styling you want and a code word to find the paragraph, then multiply the paragraph, replacing the text in that template with each word.

Your Word template would look like this:

[image: Word template]

Here's some *pseudo* code to get you started, assuming you have the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) installed

```
    var templateRegex = new Regex("\\[templateForWords\\]");
    var wordPlacementRegex = new Regex("\\[word\\]");
    var translationPlacementRegex = new Regex("\\[translation]\\]");

    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    { 
      MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

      // do your work here...
      var paragraphTemplate = mainPart.Document.Body
       .Descendants<Paragraph>()
       .Where(p=>templateRegex.IsMatch(p.InnerText)); //pseudo 
       //... or whatever gives you the text of the Para, I don't have the SDK right now

      foreach (string word in YourDictionary){
        var paraClone = paragraphTemplate.Clone(); // pseudo 

// you may need to do something like 
// paraClone.Descendents<Text>().Where(t=>regex.IsMatch(t.Value))
// to find the exact element containing template text
        paraClone.Text = templateRegex.Replace(paraClone.Text,"");// pseudo 
        paraClone.Text = wordPlacementRegex.Replace(paraClone.Text,word);
        paraClone.Text = translationPlacementRegex.Replace(paraClone.Text,YourDictionary[word]);

        paragraphTemplate.Parent.InsertAfter(paraClone,ParagraphTemplate); // pseudo
      }

      paragraphTemplate.Remove();

      // document should auto-save 
      document.Package.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: I wrote the code right after seeing the first 2 comments on my question, but thank you for your answer, I've accepted it as most helpfull. I'll need to practice with this a bit and read some of the msdn documentation again. I'm not sure why you're looking through the descendants, although I remember seeing that in msdn examples. I really like the idea of using regex though, as I love regex :D, and I'll probably incorporate it into my code.

Comment: There is a trade-off with the Productivity tool, which may or may not apply to you. If you're producing files to be read by humans you can be certain they will want things added/removed/altered as time goes on, which becomes very difficult to handle with generated code, the template approach makes it easy to change the output without changes to code. If, of course your document is just an automation step then generated code is a better choice because it has less chance of not working for whatever reason.

Comment: ... judging by your need for exact layout and font weight (bold *and* normal) I presume the output will be used by humans

Comment: By template approach, do you mean if I need to read the file first and get the, possibly new, template and then alter the file and get it back to the user? In my app the user can make a word file if he/she wants to print the dictionary or just have it as a file that can be read and/or altered in MS Word. After the file is created the app doesn't reuse it again and doesn't care about any new templates. I have a serialized file, as a binary save file, which is used by the app itself.

Comment: Could you help me with another thing? Whenever a new letter starts I append `new Break()` twice before that letter, and twice after it. Because of that the right column can start with 1 or 2 empty lines. Is there a way for me to make a condition on which I'll add the breaks after that letter or a way to format the column itself so it doesn't start with empty lines?

Comment: @VincentProxy yes, what you described is template approach, the same as my answer - you create a Word document as a template for your app, the user gets printable documents that can't be used by the app any more. The template is embedded within the app (as either content or embedded resource)

Comment: @VincentProxy I don't understand the `new Break()` question. You could post a new question and link it as a comment

Comment: I posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614286/conditional-new-break-for-multi-column-docx-file-c-sharp). Hm, I cant mention you by name with @ in comments here, but below Alex Butenko's answer I can. Not sure how this works yet xd You gave the answer so there's no need to mention you?

Comment: Yes, I get a notification even without the @. As I suspected the document is already different from the original. You'll end up with a reasonably comprehensive document processing engine in the end, make sure to keep it in its own library, they come in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

OpenXML is absolutely better, because it is faster, has less bugs, more reliable and flexible in runtime (especially in server environment). And it's not really difficult to find out how to make one or another element using OpenXML. As docx file is just a zip file with xml files inside, I open it and read the xml to get the idea, how word itself makes it. First of all, I create a document, then format it (in your case, you can create some file with two columns and bold words inside), save it, rename it to .zip file. Then open it, open "word" directory inside and the file "document.xml" inside the directory. This document contains essential part of xml, looking at this it's not difficult to figure out how to recreate it in OpenXML

Comment: Misleading. OOXML has an SDK that is easier to use than combining XML and ZIP SDKs, validates the structure and has strongly typed Linq support

Comment: @StenPetrov I didn't tell a word about using xml or zip sdk, my answer is about using OpenXML, and your answer, actually, duplicates big part of mine.

Comment: the only relevant piece of information in your answer is that a docx is a zip and the rest is "not difficult"

Comment: @StenPetrov In the answer, I explain how to find the desirable structure of OpenXml OP wants to build. From his question I assumed he knows the basic things about this library, so I don't need to explain him about WordprocessingDocument.Open and the rest. I didn't mention anything about using pure xml or zip libraries, and I don't understand where did you get it from. "Whenever you get confused unzip the docx and browse the contents to see how it's done." - is what I was talking about, and it's very relevant. Just reading documentation you'll never get the right structure.

Comment: @StenPetrov I've played around a little with .zip and xml files inside. The content looks interesting and I'll probably use it together with Productivity tool

Answer (score 0):

Open XML is a much better option than Office COM. But the problem is that it is a low-level file format library that unlike Office COM doesn’t work on a high abstraction level. You might want to go that route but I recommend you to first consider looking into a commercial library that will give you the benefits of a high-level DOM without the need to have MS Word installed on the production machine. Our company recently purchased [this toolkit](http://www.docentric.com/) which allows you to use template based approach and also DOM/programmatic approach to generate/modify/create documents.

Comment: Does this toolkit let you bold part of the text as asked in the question?