# Conditional new Break for multi-column docx file, C#

Tags: c#, multiple-columns, docx

This is a follow-up question for [Creating Word file from ObservableCollection with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598042/creating-word-file-from-observablecollection-with-c-sharp).
I have a .docx file with a `Body` that has 2 columns for its `SectionProperties`. I have a dictionary of foreign words with their translation. On each line I need [Word] = [Translation] and whenever a new letter starts it should be in its own line, with 2 or 3 line breaks before and after that letter, like this:

> **A**
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> **A-word** = translation
>   **A-word** = translation
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> **B**
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> **B-word** = translation
>   **B-word** = translation
>   ...

I structured this in a for loop, so that in every iteration I'm creating a new paragraph with a possible `Run` for the letter (if a new one starts), a `Run` for the word and a `Run` for the translation. So the `Run` with the first letter is in the same `Paragraph` as the word and translation `Run` and it appends 2 or 3 `Break` objects before and after the `Text`.
In doing  so the second column can sometimes start with 1 or 2 empty lines. Or the first column on the next page can start with empty lines.
This is what I want to avoid.

So my question is, can I somehow check if the end of the page is reached, or the text is at the top of the column, so I don't have to add a `Break`? Or, can I format the `Column` itself so that it doesn't start with an empty line?

I have tried putting the letter `Run` in a separate, optional, `Paragraph`, but again, I find myself having to input line breaks and the problem remains.

Comment: If I understand your questions right, you can achieve that using table with one column. invisible borders and the option "Allow row to break across pages" set false. Using table you can have more control over content alignment.

Comment: @AlexButenko There need to be 2 columns, not just 1. I haven't used tables yet, but the way I see it the question remains pretty much the same. If I use 1 table, with 2 columns, per page, can I somehow detect the last row in the first column, so that I don't start the second column with empty rows?

Comment: no, page layout still has two columns, but table has only one. And you just put every new piece of your content to the new talbe row

Comment: @AlexButenko So I just have 1 table, with 1 column, per page, but when I set the page layout to 2 columns it will break my table into two pieces, first half for the first page column, second half for the second column? What exactly does "allow row to break across pages" do? I still need 2 empty rows before the row that has the letter, and 2 empty rows after it. Wouldn't I still get empty (table) rows at the beginning of the page?

Comment: Making your page layout two columns doesn't split table. Table can continue further on other pages. It just starts on the left half of the first page, continues on the right half of the first page, then continues on the left part of second page and so on. and you split your content to table rows. And you can set this rows so table row starts on the new page or at the start of right part of the page if it doesn't fit previous page.

Comment: @AlexButenko That's what I meant by "split". :) I may not be getting what you're trying to tell me, but this just looks like a more complicated version of what I did and doesn't solve my problem at all.

Comment: ok, I didn't post it as answer anyway, because I don't really understand your question. I thought I do, but I guess, no.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598878/1416035) you can extend the template capability.
Use the Productivity tool to generate a single page break object, something like:

```
private readonly Paragraph PageBreakPara = new Paragraph(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page}));
```

Make a helper method that finds containers of a text tag:

public IEnumerable FindElements(OpenXmlCompositeElement searchParent, string tagRegex)
  where T: OpenXmlElement
{ 
    var regex = new Regex(tagRegex);

```
return searchParent.Descendants() 
    .Where(e=>(!(e is OpenXmlCompositeElement) 
              && regex.IsMatch(e.InnerText)))
    .SelectMany(e => 
        e.Ancestors()
            .OfType<T>()
            .Union(e is T ? new T[] { (T)e } : new T[] {} ))
    .ToList(); // can skip, prevents reevaluations
```

}

And another one that duplicates a range from the document and deletes range:

```
public IEnumerable<T> DuplicateRange<T>(OpenXmlCompositeElement root, string tagRegex)
  where T: OpenXmlElement
{ 
// tagRegex must describe exactly two tags, such as [pageStart] and [pageEnd]
// or [page] [/page] - or whatever pattern you choose

  var tagElements = FindElements(root, tagRegex);
  var fromEl = tagElements.First();
  var toEl = tagElements.Skip(1).First(); // throws exception if less than 2 el

// you may want to find a common parent here
// I'll assume you've prepared the template so the elements are siblings.

  var result = new List<OpenXmlElement>();

  var step = fromEl.NextSibling();
  while (step !=null && toEl!=null && step!=toEl){
   // another method called DeleteRange will instead delete elements in that range within this loop
    var copy = step.CloneNode();
    toEl.InsertAfterSelf(copy);
    result.Add(copy);
    step = step.NextSibling();
  }

  return result;
}


public IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> ReplaceTag(OpenXmlCompositeElement parent, string tagRegex, string replacement){
  var replaceElements = FindElements<OpenXmlElement>(parent, tagRegex);
  var regex = new Regex(tagRegex);
  foreach(var el in  replaceElements){
     el.InnerText = regex.Replace(el.InnerText, replacement);
  }

  return replaceElements;
}
```

Now you can have a document that looks like this:

[page] 
[TitleLetter]

[WordTemplate][Word]: [Translation] [/WordTemplate]

[pageBreak]
[/page]

With that document you can duplicate the [page]..[/page] range, process it per letter and once you're out of letters - delete the template range:

var vocabulary = Dictionary>;

```
foreach (var letter in vocabulary.Keys.OrderByDescending(c=>c)){
  // in reverse order because the copy range comes after the template range
  var pageTemplate = DuplicateRange(wordDocument,"\\[/?page\\]");

  foreach (var p in pageTemplate.OfType<OpenXmlCompositeElement>()){

    ReplaceTag(p, "[TitleLetter]",""+letter);
    var pageBr = ReplaceTag(p, "[pageBreak]","");
    if (pageBr.Any()){
      foreach(var pbr in pageBr){
       pbr.InsertAfterSelf(PageBreakPara.CloneNode()); 
      }
    }
    var wordTemplateFound = FindElements(p, "\\[/?WordTemplate\\]");
    if (wordTemplateFound .Any()){
       foreach (var word in vocabulary[letter].Keys){
          var wordTemplate = DuplicateRange(p, "\\[/?WordTemplate\\]")
              .First(); // since it's a single paragraph template
          ReplaceTag(wordTemplate, "\\[/?WordTemplate\\]","");
          ReplaceTag(wordTemplate, "\\[Word]",word);
          ReplaceTag(wordTemplate, "\\[Translation\\]",vocabulary[letter][word]);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

...Or something like it.

- Look into SdtElements if things start getting too complicated
- Don't use AltChunk despite the popularity of that answer, it requires Word to open and process the file, so you can't use some library to make a PDF out of it
- Word documents are messy, the solution above should work (haven't tested) but the template must be carefully crafted, make backups of your template often
- making a robust document engine isn't easy (since Word is messy), do the minimum you need and rely on the template being in your control (not user-editable).
- the code above is far from optimized or streamlined, I've tried to condense it in the smallest footprint possible at the cost of presentability. There are probably bugs too :)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. It's a little overwhelming right now. Looks fairly complicated, but I think I get the general idea. I only found out about Open XML SDK a few days ago and I don't feel comfortable using some code unless I know exactly what every single line does and why it's there. I'll need some time breaking your code down and generally learning more about Open XML and docx.